# É possível criar uma trigger que invoque um web service?

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-service, integração

Estou trabalhando na integração de duas bases de dados.

É um sistema que precisa do status dos funcionários no RH.

Por questões de performance, não posso apontar todas as consultas que dependam dos funcionários para a base do RH, o que fiz foi criar uma funcionalidade para importar esses dados para minha base.

Atualmente criei em meu sistema uma funcionalidade que em certos intervalos de tempo busca os dados da base do RH.

Mas gostaria de mudar a implementação para algo do tipo, quando o dado na base for alterado, invocar um webService em meu sistema que vai importar os dados do RH, e atualizar minha base.

Como podemos trabalhar apenas na base de dados, e não no sistema RH, pensei se seria possível criar uma trigger na base de dados RH que dispare meu processo no outro sistema.

É possível, então, criar uma trigger no SQL Server que invoque um webService?

Comment: Não dá pra fazer um Linked Server? Seria muito mais simples e eficiente.

Comment: @utluiz Eu gostaria de evitar essa abordagem. Para que meu sistema seja mais independente da base de dados do RH. Me preocupo também em não ser o responsável por uma queda de performance no sistema RH ao longo do dia, por isso preferi importar os dados ao invés de consultá-los diretamente.

Comment: Então, na verdade, eficiente não seria, porque Linked Server, dependendo do Hardware, acaba fazendo com que o banco, como um todo, perca muita velocidade... Eu fiquei sabendo, através de conversas com DBA's, que se consegue linkar uma DLL no banco, usando-a como se fosse uma função, você poderia procurar se informar sobre isso, é uma ótima saída para esse tipo de situação.

Comment: @BetaSystems-RodrigoDuarte O que você quer dizer com "dependendo do hardware"? Em que ponto (a não ser uma implementação ruim) uma conexão direta de uma instância do SQL Server com outra pode ser superior a você invocar um serviço de um sistema que, por sua vez, vai conectar-se ao banco e gravar a informação?

Comment: Ah sim, desculpe, me expressei errado, na verdade, o que eu quis dizer é o Linked Server de um servidor, físico, para o outro é que, dependendo do Hardware dos servidores, pode fazer com que o banco fique mais devagar, esse foi o intuito, não de uma instância para a outra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ficando apenas no mérito da questão sobre invocação de web service a partir de um trigger, há [este artigo](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428200/How-to-invoke-a-Web-Service-from-a-Stored-Procedur) em inglês.

A lógica é utilizar a procedure [sp_OAMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms174984.aspx) a qual permite chamar um método a partir de um objeto OLE.

```sql
DECLARE @Param1 INT
DECLARE @obj INT
DECLARE @valorRetorno INT
DECLARE @url VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @response VARCHAR(4000)

SET @Param1 = 35

SET @url = 'http://localhost/WebServices/Service1.asmx?Param1=' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Param1) + ''

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'Get', @url, false
EXEC sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT

SELECT @response AS Param1
EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj
```

A variável `@response` contém o código de retorno da chamada GET.

Há outras maneiras, como invocando DLLs que fazem chamada a web services.
Outros artigos, em inglês:

- http://harshilnshah.blogspot.in/2013/03/call-webservice-from-stored-procedure.html
- http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2008/11/11/calling-a-web-service-from-sql-server-2005/
- http://www.sqlservergeeks.com/forums/microsoft-data-platform/sql-server-bi/9/sql-programming-calling-the-web-service-thru-sql